# Vim Syntax Match In A Region

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I've a syntax after file for *Java*. It works, cause I already defined some syntax keywords, matches and regions, which are successfully highlighted.
Not I want to highlight some matches, which are within a highlight region I defined before. My intention was that the region get highlighted first and the matches afterwards draw over this region parts.
The exact use case are the function/class/... descriptions with thei documentation keywords like `@author`, `@version`, ... Therfore I wrote the following into my syntax file:

```
syntax region _Comment start="\/\*" end="\*\/"
syntax match _CommentKey "^\s*\*\s*\zs@\w*\ze\s"

highlight link _Comment Comment
highlight link _CommentKey Special
```

No I have two problems. I test both independently and the comment region works fine. The comment key match only works without the `\zs` part, so it highlight also the leading `*`. As soon as I add the `\zs` nothing is highlighted anymore. How can I solve this? For other matches this works fine.
The second problem: I don't them combined. If I enable both rules, only the whole section will be highlighted as `Comment`. I doesn't matter where I place the second rule, it will not be highlighted. Also I tried to use the `skip` for the region, until I realiszed it is meant for something different.
Any ideas? Thanks!

**Example code to test:**

```
/**
 * Function description here.
 *
 * @param id
 * @author Max Mustermann
 */
private static int function foo(final int id) {
  return id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax regions, which have nested matches must allow them:

```
syntax region _Comment start="\/\*" end="\*\/" contains=_CommentKey
```

Have a look at `:h syn-contains`

For your first Problem, you should read `:h syn-pattern` there you'll find the following sentence:

> Syntax patterns are always interpreted like the 'magic' option is set,
>   no matter what the actual value of 'magic' is.

See `:h magic` for that. Your regex must escape `@` in magic mode.

```
"^\s*\*\s*\zs\@\w*\ze\s"
```

should work fine

Comment: Awesome! I start reading the documentation for syntax but haven't reached this section so far. I'm sorry.

Comment: no problem, I'll update shortly for your first problem

Comment: Looks like it isn't a problem anymore... I rly don't know why, but know it works perfectly.

Comment: isn't just the whole line highlighted as `_CommentKey` ?

Comment: Was so, but since I use the `contains` it simply works so, that for example only `@author` is highlighted.

Comment: But I tried ur approach to escape already and get always the error: E871: (NFA regexp) Can't have a multi follow a multi !
E62: Nested \@

Comment: strange, don't know that one. Hopefully one of the guys who really understand vim have a look and explains it to us.